# How to inspect om objects?

Tags: clojurescript, om

I've been following the om tutorial. Im using Light Table to setup an External Browser connection. Additionally, in my clojurescript code I'm calling `(enable-console-print!)` to send my println statements to the browser console.

The problem is that when I print an om component.. something like:

`(println (om/build my-component-function my-data))`

The output I get is:

`#<[object Object]>`

I have the same issue if I just eval `(om/build my-component-function my-data)` in LightTable.

Being able to inspect this object will be helpful for debugging. How can I print something more meaningful?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1 Try using `(.log js/console object)` which is ClojureScript equivalent of `console.log(object);`

2 You may also install [React Developer Tools extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi), which will allow you to browse React/Om components you have on page

Comment: I would also like to add that (dom/render-to-str) has been very helpful with debugging (https://github.com/swannodette/om/wiki/Documentation#render-to-str)

Answer (score 3):

As you can read on the README file of Om project https://github.com/swannodette/om

You can use [ankha](https://github.com/noprompt/ankha), an EDN inspector view. Then you can print as edn your component and pass to ankha. Other solution can be `(.dir js/console object)` and you will be able to inspect your component on firebug or chrome console

Comment: Just tried ankha but it doesn't seem to work for om/build objects. It will still print #<[object Object]>. Thanks for the tip though, works great for other clojure objects.

Comment: @sthomps did you try (.dir js/console component) ?

Comment: (.dir js/console component) spits out a list of functions defined in the object but doesnt provide info on the dom element its trying to render or the data I passed in.

Answer (score 3):

Try [cljs-devtools](https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-devtools). This library leverages "custom formatters" to pretty-print clojure data structures in Chrome Javascript Console.

When you enable custom formatters and integrate library in your project this should pretty print your object:

```
(.log js/console your_namespace.your_object)
```

Also typing in the console should work (with code completion)

```
your_namespace.your_object
```

Disclaimer: This feature is experimental in Chrome Dev Tools and I'm author of the library.